# Segue after Facebook login objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, segue

My app will not transition to the next view controller after logging into Facebook. I am declaring the segue manually as follows. I am at a lost as to why this is not working. My storyboard initially goes to the FBLoginView and then I am trying to segue (modal) to Tab Bar View Controller with my other view controllers attached.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
// Logged-in user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMain" sender: self];
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMain" sender: self]` to ensure control is reaching that line?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your SegueIdentifier attribute? sometimes I put one uppercase letter in one place and lowercase in another. Just make sure the "showMain" is the same in the SegueIdentifier attribute.